# Mongo groupby dynamic range

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I know the question title is not that clear. If anyone has better title, please suggest after reading my question:

I have epoch value stored as integer in my documents.
I need to group them by a number specified by user.

**eg.** `35` is the epoch and the user has specified a value `5`
I need the group with `35,36,37,38,39` then `40,41,42,43,44` and so on...

How do i do it? I have the logic before and after this process but not able to figure out this grouping.